# Unable to use Google Assistant App on Work Profile

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to use the Work Profile version of the Google Assistant app, but I cannot get past the "set default assist app" screen in order to start using Google Assistant. It works on some phones, but not on my Pixel 3 or a Pixel 2 XL that I tested it on.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Tap on the Work Profile Google Assistant app, and a screen appears to prompt the me to set the default assist app
2. Tap on "Settings".
3. When I tap on "Assist App", the "Permission Controller" screen opens briefly and then closes immediately.
4. Finally any more taps on "Assist App" again has touch feedback show nothing.

[Image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSOkO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your work account as permission to access your voice.

Go to the Activity Controls page.
Sign in with your [Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols)
Enable the following permissions:

- Web & App Activity
- Under Web & App Activity, check the box next to Include Chrome history and activity from sites, apps, and devices that use Google services.

If that doesn't work, this can be due to limitations or restrictions with work accounts. Contact your admin.

Comment: Did not seem to work, I enabled it and restarted my phone but like b efore nothing exists in the Assist App screen.